# fa-houzz icon is not displaying on my website but other font-awesome icons do display properly

Tags: font-awesome

I cannot seem to get this icon to work. However, most of the other icons do work. Spreifically, if I use  the icon shows up but if I use  it does not.

Comment: Posting the HTML you're using to display the icon might help find the issue. Also you mention *most* of the other icons work - which others don't work?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an ad blocker, some of the icons in the ["brand" section](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/#brand) are hidden.

This is mentioned on the Font Awesome (FA hereafter) website; however, one may tend to forget this after using FA for a while. The same happened to me; luckily, I did some cross-browser testing and found that the icon was displayed in the other browser just fine.

To check if it's the ad blocker, disable the ad blocker temporarily. Or view the page in a different browser that doesn't have an ad blocker enabled.

To solve this, you must rename the respective icon classes in the FA CSS file. This is, of course, not too elegant as you have to do it after each update of FA. But this is still the most easy and straightforward way.

Answer (score 0):

This problem still persists even when you update the version to the latest version of font awesome so here is css solution ,as I have done this on the url at the end :

```
.fa.fa-houzz:before {
   font-family: FontAwesome;
   content: " \f27c ";
   display: inline-block;
   padding-right: 3px;
   vertical-align: middle;
   color: #7ac143;
    }
```

In content'' the unicode is called for houzz icon that will work for you definitely.

http://midwestpropertyprofessionals.com/